# Is it always required to call an object all the way through the chain (or in order)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to look through reddit's API. I have seen a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/170/) where they grab the image url from the site. However, I'm confused as to how they are getting the objects themselves. In their`each()`statement, they used `data.data.children` and `item.data.url`, however I cannot find a data object right after another data object in the json here `http://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json`. I also do not see `item.data.url`. if I look from the very beginning (the two first objects are "kind" and "data"). What does this mean?

Comment: `data` is just the name of the parameter passed to the callback function – and if the JSON data structure received contains a property named `data`, then of course that means that it has to be addressed as `data.data` here. Change that parameter name to `foo`, and `foo.data` would be used to address the `data` property of the JSON data structure …

Answer (score 4):

Given the code in the fiddle:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function(data) {
    $.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");
    });
});
```

`data` and `item` are both function parameters, and their names have no relation to any named key within the JSON.

The parameter `data` represents the entire JSON structure, but as it's just a parameter whose name is not significant I shall call it `foo` instead to disambiguate it from the contents of that structure, hence `foo.data` refers to the child element named `data` *within* the first level of the JSON.

The `item` parameter represents each element in the array `foo.data.children`, so `item.data.url` for the first item would be equivalent to `data.children[0].data.url` within the JSON.

Comment: right... I have no idea why I didn't see the data parameter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the JSON returned is:

```
{
    data: {
        after: "",
        before: null,
        children: [
            {
                data: {
                    url: ""
                }
            },
            ...
        ],
        modhash: ""
    },
    kind: "Listing"
}
```

The name of the result variable is called `data` in the callback function parameters. So to get to the children you need to type:

```
data.data.children;
```

Next, in the `$.each` loop, each entry from the `children` array is assigned to an `item` variable in that callback function. It is from there where you drill down to the `url`. property (`item.data.url`).

You could name these whatever you want if `data.data` is confusing.